# How to create Spark broadcast variable from Java String array?

Tags: apache-spark

I have Java String array which contains 45 string which is basically column names

```
String[] fieldNames = {"colname1","colname2",...};
```

Currently I am storing above array of String in a Spark driver in a static field. My job is running slow so trying to refactor code. I am using above String array while creating a DataFrame

```
DataFrame dfWithColNames = sourceFrame.toDF(fieldNames);
```

I want to do the above using broadcast variable to that it don't ship huge string array to every executor. I believe we can do something like the following to create broadcast

```
String[] brArray = sc.broadcast(fieldNames,String[].class);//gives compilation error 

DataFrame df = sourceFrame.toDF(???);//how do I use above broadcast can I use it as is by passing brArray
```

I am new to Spark.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The return variable of `sc.broadcast` is of type `Broadcast<String[]>` and not `String[]`. When you want to access the value, you simply call value() on the variable. From your example it would be like:

```
Broadcast<String[]> broadcastedFieldNames = sc.broadcast(fieldNames)
DataFrame df = sourceFrame.toDF(broadcastedFieldNames.value())
```

Note, that if you are writing this in Java, you probably want to wrap the SparkContext within the JavaSparkContext. It makes everything easier and you can then avoid having to pass a ClassTag to the broadcast function.

You can read more on broadcasting variables on http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables

Comment: JavaSparkContext explanation is good, so that i dont have to include classtag.

Answer (score 23):

This is a bit old question, however, I hope my solution would help somebody.

In order to broadcast any object (could be a single POJO or a collection) with Spark 2+ you first need to have the following method that creates a classTag for you:

```
private static <T> ClassTag<T> classTag(Class<T> clazz) {
   return scala.reflect.ClassManifestFactory.fromClass(clazz);
}
```

next you use a JavaSparkContext from a SparkSession to broadcast your object as previously:

```
   sparkSession.sparkContext().broadcast(
            yourObject,
            classTag(YourObject.class)
    )
```

In case of a collection, say, java.util.List, you use the following:

```
    sparkSession.sparkContext().broadcast(
            yourObject,
            classTag(List.class)
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    ArrayList<String> dataToBroadcast = new ArrayList();
    dataToBroadcast .add("string1");
    ...
    dataToBroadcast .add("stringn");
                        
  //Creating the broadcast variable
  //No need to write classTag code by hand use akka.japi.Util which is available
                    
  Broadcast<ArrayList<String>> strngBrdCast = spark.sparkContext().broadcast(
                                      dataToBroadcast,
                                      akka.japi.Util.classTag(ArrayList.class));
                        
    //Here is the catch.When you are iterating over a Dataset, 
    //Spark will actally run it in distributed mode. So if you try to accees
    //Your object directly (e.g. dataToBroadcast) it would be null . 
    //Cause you didn't ask spark to explicitly send tha outside variable to each
    //machine where you are running this for each parallelly.
    //So you need to use Broadcast variable.(Most common use of Broadcast)  
    
    someSparkDataSetWhere.foreach((row) -> {
     ArrayList<String> stringlist = strngBrdCast.value();
     ...
     ...
    })
```